# put banner below tab host for one activity only

Tags: android, android-layout

is it  possible to put banner below tab host and in that banner there are two buttons and i want to access that two button from currently visible activity???

for example there are two xml file one is tab-host and another one is activity xml file. In tab-host xml file i have written code like this

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:background="#FFB5C5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="No track info available..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now if i want to put banner below tab host i have to write code in this file for that banner...

now but the main problem is that in banner there is two button which is accessing by the activity which has

```
     setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

not

```
      setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
```

so i will not access banner from

```
      setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

so can anybody suggest me how to do that thing

below is image

[image]

u can see that banner is below from tab host

and now i want to access banner from first activity..... o

Comment: banner resides in tabActivity and you want to access from tab content activity??

Comment: Please read http://d.android.com/design carefully and don't use a `TabHost` designed as tabs from iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that.

1. Put code to create banner and click of it in to the TabActivity.
2. show the banner only in the Activity you want otherwise set its visibility to "GONE" in other activity.
3. Done.

By above explaination you can able to see the Banner only or your desire Activity and also achieve the click of the button from that activity.

Hope you got my point.

feel free for any comments.